# Set the height of a UITextView from a UIViewController's viewWillAppear event

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I'm trying to set the height of a UITextView from a UIViewController's viewWillAppear event, here's the code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    textView.text = blah blah...
    textView.frame = CGRectMake(textView.frame.origin.x, textView.frame.origin.y,
      textView.frame.size.width, textView.frame.size.height-20);
}
```

However, it seems to ignore my sizing, it's as though after this event is called, the textview is resized by something else.

What am i doing wrong? Is there some good way to do this?

Thanks

-edit-

Got it working by putting the code in my viewDidAppear instead of the viewWillAppear.
So it works now.

Although i'm puzzled why i need to do this (remove 20 pixels from the bottom) - i mean shouldn't it resize to fill automatically? Why is it resizing to 20px too long? There's a tab bar at the bottom and a nav bar up the top. Is that confusing it?

Answer (score 2):

Simple but obvious question, does the text change, in other words, is the outlet hooked up in IB?

JUSTA TIP: Look at using the helper functions for CGRect such as:

```
textView.frame = CGRectInset(textView.frame, 0, 20);
```

Comment: Of course, the outlet's hooked up. I've just managed to get it to work anyway, by putting the code in the viewDidAppear - sweet.

Answer (score 1):

In an app with just this code and a single TextView the resizing occurs as expected. So..it's definitely something else in your app.

Are you maybe referencing the contentsize property or something else in your viewDidAppear?

Comment: Well, i've gotten it working by putting the resize code in the viewDidAppear. Now i'm curious why having it in the viewWillAppear didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by putting the code in my viewDidAppear instead of the viewWillAppear.
So it works now.

Although i'm puzzled why i need to do this (remove 20 pixels from the bottom) - i mean shouldn't it resize to fill automatically? Why is it resizing to 20px too long? There's a tab bar at the bottom and a nav bar up the top.